# SSZipArchive sometimes creates corrupt 22 bytes zip file

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, zip

We are using the **SSZipArchive** method **createZipFileAtPath:withFilesAtPaths:** in order to compress a single log file, which is then uploaded to Amazon S3. All files are located in our mobile app's **NSTemporaryDirectory()**.

Sometimes, when I download the resulting zip files from Amazon to my mac and double-click them, I get the following error:

```
Archive Utility
Unable to expand "[file name].zip" into "[folder name]".
(Error 1 - Operation not permitted.)
```

When this happens, I always notice that the file size is 22 bytes. This seems too small. When the files behave OK they are usually 1 mb or more.

Here is the relevant code from our app:

```
-(void) sendConsoleLog
{
    //NSError * error;
    //NSString * sTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self logFilePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:[self compressedLogFilePath] withFilesAtPaths:@[[self logFilePath]]];
    [self upload];
}

-(void) upload
{
    _sDestinationFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"logs/%@.zip", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

    AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression *expression = [AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression new];
    expression.progressBlock = self.progressBlock;
    [expression setValue:@"public-read" forRequestHeader:@"x-amz-acl"];

    AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];

    NSString * sFileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", [self compressedLogFilePath]];
    [[transferUtility uploadFile:[NSURL URLWithString:sFileURL]
                          bucket:S3_BUCKET_NAME
                             key:_sDestinationFileName
                     contentType:@"application/octet-stream"
                      expression:expression
                completionHander:self.completionHandler] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"cclChatSendLog continueWithBlock Error: %@", task.error);
        }
        if (task.exception) {
            NSLog(@"cclChatSendLog continueWithBlock Exception: %@", task.exception);
        }
        if (task.result) {
            AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask = task.result;
            NSUInteger iTaskID = uploadTask.taskIdentifier;
            NSLog(@"cclChatSendLog.h %lu continueWithBlock: Uploading...", (unsigned long)iTaskID);
        }
        return nil;
    }];
}

-(NSString*) logFilePath
{
    NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"console%lu.log",(unsigned long)(appDelegate.hash)];
    return [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}

-(NSString*) compressedLogFilePath
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip", [self logFilePath]];
}
```

I wonder if the 22 bytes zip is created in case there is no file found in [self logFilePath]. Has anyone encountered a similar behaviour?

Comment: `createZipFileAtPath:withFilesAtPaths:` returns a `BOOL` value. What about checking it and see if it's equals to FALSE when you have theses 22 bytes files?

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.

Comment: We are seeing the same issue on iOS using Swift... 22 byte zip files.  We are looking at the flag it it return TRUE... otherwise the file would not be uploaded.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: I added a separate check that verifies that there is an actual file at the path before compressing, and that seems to solve this.

Comment: 22 bytes is an empty zip file, it is minimum size of zip file and not corrupt.  I am seeing this problem in my iOS app.  Zipping had been working fine previously.  Now it is broken.  The input files exists.  The zip file exists.  However, zip file is 22 bytes. react-native-zip-archive 6.0.8 uses SSZipArchive 2.2.3